# Which is better: getInputMap().remove(..) or set Action to "none"?

Tags: java, swing, keystroke

[Java tuturial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) says that "To make a component ignore a key that it normally responds to, you can use the special action name "none". For example, the following code makes a component ignore the F2 key:

```
component.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F2"), "none");
```

"

And there is a method `getInputMap().remove(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F2"));`

What is the difference? Why to use the first method?

Comment: It may have something to do with there being 3 input maps for each component.

Comment: I am guessing "none" is the better choice, because `getInputMap()` returns a normally empty InputMap whose parent is the look-and-feel-installed InputMap.  So calling `remove` will remove your custom key binding, but will not disable any binding for F2 that was installed by the look-and-feel.

Comment: I think this is the answer to my question. Of course, it depends on situation which method to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand a little on VGR's comment, using "none" will only affect a single component. Using remove() on the components InputMap will also only affect that component.

You could also `remove` the binding from the LAF InputMap:

```
component.getInputMap().getParent().remove(...);
```

In this case the binding is removed for all components of that class. This will affect any component that has been created or will be created in your application.

> you can use the special action name "none".

Also, "none" is not a special name. It is just a value that is used when a lookup is done on the ActionMap. If no Action is found using this value then nothing happens.